# CSS ::before element should not trigger :hover functionality of the parent element

Tags: html, css

As I'm working on a wordpress site I can only add CSS classes to the manu in order to customize it. My goal is to add some text before the menu item, which works pretty good:

```
#nav-menu-container .myheader-heading::before {
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#nav-menu-container .myheader-heading-text::before {
  content: "text";
}
```

Here is the HTML of the main element:

```
<li id="menu-item-213" class="myheader-heading myheader-heading-text menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-213"><a href="#">Some Nav Link</a></li>
```

It looks good, but everytime I hover over the text, which is defined with the aforementioned CSS with `::before`, the main element get's highlighted, which is pretty annoying. How can I avoid that behaviour, so that the text before the main element does not effect the hover capabilities of the main element?

**EDIT**

Also I tried to disable or revert any hover functionality in `#nav-menu-container .myheader-heading:hover::before` but it only effects the `::before` elements, not the main one, which still gets hovered.

Comment: revert the hover style (you didn't post) on the ::before pseudoelement

Comment: probably this `pointer-events: none;` ?

Comment: @fcalderan I tried that, but `#nav-menu-container .myheader-heading:hover::before` effects only the `::before` element, not the main one.

Comment: Could you include a demo or a link?

Answer (score -1):

Take your pseudos out of the flow (i.e. use position absolute) and use `pointer-events:none` on your pseudos

```css
ul, li{
  margin: 0; 
  list-style-type:none;
}
ul{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.myheader-heading{
  margin-top:20px;
  position:relative;
}

.myheader-heading::before {
  font-size: 11px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-100%; left:0;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 5px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.myheader-heading-text::before {
  content: "text";
  pointer-events:none;
}

.myheader-heading:hover{
  background:red;
}

body{
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item-2" class="myheader-heading myheader-heading-text menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-213"><a href="#">Some Nav Link</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1" class="myheader-heading myheader-heading-text menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-213"><a href="#">Other Nav Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

adjust as needed.

Comment: Does not work, added it, to the `::before` elements, but still the parent get's hovered when the mouse is over the text.

Comment: @chevallier you need to take those pseudos out of the flow (i.e. use position absolute). Check my updated answer

Comment: In theory you made it, but practically I would not use it, because working with `position:absolute` makes things too complicated. Also, margin/padding do not effect the surrounding elements properly. Anyway, thank you for you efforts.

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct behavior for the `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes. If you want to disable that, you can add `pointer-events: none;` to them.